# Ubuntu 14.04 freezing (fully) randomly

Tags: 14.04, unity, ati, freeze

Probably this question has been asked many times, but have this problem that Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity freezes randomly on my HP Probook 4540s (Intel and AMD graphics) laptop. Wheter it's when using browser or doing something else. And sometimes it happens like 10 seconds after waking up from suspend mode. And when it freezes, it freezes completely, mouse doesn't move, no reacton from keyboard, nothing. I have tried that REISUB thing many times - nothing. So I have to reset it by power button. 
But this freezing isn't happening on Xubuntu, which I'm right now using. So it might have to do something with Unity? Would upgrading to 14.10 solve the issue?

Edit: after waking up from suspend, freezup happens every time. so it's basically inavoidable.  So it looks like the only way to prevent it from freezing after wake up would be to turn off computer, and not leting it suspend itself or do it manually.
But random freezing can happen still happen too.

Comment: Temperatures are all good.

Comment: If I would have something like that, I would turn off disk caching for my system partition so I could at least check the logs afterwards...  (Did you check the logs?)

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: Which kernel are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Graphic driver? in about this PC -I have Spanish version hehe- you can see which video driver has your notebook. Commonly Ubuntu installs the default driver (Gallium 0.4 on AMD Mullins), if you have some similar you must go to additional drivers and install the AMD private video driver (fglrx-updates), reboot and verify again your video driver